# What is the proper algorithm to trace time conflict in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, datetime, time

I'm working with a time scheduling project where I can schedule materials by time and I am really really confused on how can I trace the time conflict within a time range. I worked with many(I think) algorithms but still no luck. My brain is saturated that's why I ask anyone here who can help me.

So I have these data in my database:

```
    CREATE TABLE schedule_dummy
    (
    `materialID` int,
    `date_reserve` date,
    `start_time` time,
    `end_time` time
    );

   ------DB Table schedule_dummy --------
   material |        date     |   start_time  | end_time   
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    7       |    2013-08-01   |  13:00:00     | 14:00:00    
   10       |    2013-09-01   |  13:30:00     | 14:00:00    
    ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I used this data to check the availability of a certain material in a particular time. And so if the value of `start_time` and`end_time` is `equal to` or `in between` those time in the database the material will not be available. I tried so many query but doesn't work with many cases.
 Here are some queries that i've tried so far.

```
   $sql = "SELECT materialID
          FROM schedule_dummy WHERE (date_reserve = ?)
          AND (? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
          OR ? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)";
```

And

```
   //I've tried this query but in some cases doesn't work dunno if I'm missing something.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule_dummy
        WHERE date_reserve = ?
        AND start_time >=? AND start_time <=?";
```

And here's my php code Note:I'm using codeigniter:

```
   $start =  date("H:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('start')));
    $end =  date("H:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('end')));
    $date_reserve =  $this->input->post('date_reserve');
    $id =  $this->input->post('id');


    //$sql = "SELECT materialID FROM schedule_dummy WHERE (date_reserve = ?) AND (? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time OR ? BETWEEN start_time AND end_time)";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM schedule_dummy WHERE date_reserve = ? AND start_time >=? AND end_time <=?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($date_reserve,$start,$end));

    $ids = array();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        foreach($query->result() as $rows){
            $ids[] = $rows->materialID;
        }
    }

    $data = array();
    $n = count($ids);

    $idz = array();
        if($n > 0){
            $q = $this->db->select('*')->where_not_in('id',$ids)->where('cid', $id)->get('materials');

            if($q->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach($q->result() as $row){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }

        }else{
            $q = $this->db->select('*')->where('cid',$id)->get('materials');

            if($q->num_rows() > 0 ){
                foreach($q->result() as $row){
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }

        }
        return $data;
```

So could anyone who knows some algorithm to trace the time conflict? So that I can retrieve those available materials in my database? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if an item is being used on a date and particluar time, the following should do the trick for you:

```
select
    material
from
    schedule_dummy
where
    date_reserve=checkDate
    and start_time <= checkTime
    and end_time >= checkTime
```

Comment: Okay, now we are getting somewhere. What is the exact time you are trying and what is the rows of data that should be matched to it?

Comment: E.g. start_time = 13:30:00 and end_time = 14:00:00

Comment: What time are you testing it against? Please show your input time, start time and end time that it should be matched against in the database.

Comment: that's it when I inputed 13:30:00 to 14:00:00 it only gives me one record. It should be all the data in the database will be retrieved

Comment: It sounds like it should have based on your code - however you haven't posted your PHP code. Are you sure that you aren't only reading the first row of data from the results?

Comment: Sorry I've changed the data recently. Wait ill update it together with my php code

Answer (score 0):

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE day='$day' AND starttime>='$starttime' AND endtime<'$endtime'";
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
        if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $errmsg_arr[] = 'The Room or Time Schedule is  already exist in the database';
                $errflag = true;
            }
            @mysql_free_result($result);
        }
        else {
            die("Query failed");
        }


    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        echo "<script>alert('The Room or Time Schedule is  already exist in the database.');history.back();</script>";
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue